# How to stop user from leaving page after submitting form (i.e. while it's processing)?

Tags: javascript

There are lots of similar questions on here, but I haven't found any that deal with stopping a user from leaving a page **after** submitting a form (i.e. while it's processing).

I have a page on my website with a form that takes a long time to submit (sometimes as long as 15 seconds), so I want to have a popup warning to keep the user on the page after they submit the form.

The problem is that no matter how I try using `window.onbeforeunload`, I always get a confirmation dialog from that function when the form is submitted, which is not what I want. I don't want the user to get the confirmation dialog when the form is submitted, but rather after it's submitted and only if they try to leave the page after that.

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="formSubmitted();">
    <button type="submit" onclick="return checkForm();">submit form</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
formSubmittedFlag = 0;

function checkForm()
{
    ...

    if(...)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


function formSubmitted()
{
    formSubmittedFlag = 1;
}



window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    if(formSubmittedFlag == 1)
    {
        return "Are you sure you want to leave the page?";
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm wanting?

Comment: You do realize you have a variable and a function with the same name?

Comment: @Musa - This is actually a dumbed down version of my real code, in which the function and variable names are different. I'm glad you pointed this out, though, because I wasn't aware that was an issue.

Comment: Why would you want to hinder your users close the tab? The request is already sent to your server, where it will be processed correctly. If the user does not want to wait for feedback, he should be able to do so.

Comment: @Bergi - It's a checkout page, so the user really needs to stay on the page to see if there were errors processing the order. I don't think any users would intentionally leave the page, so this is me trying to protect users from accidentally closing the page after submitting the form.

Comment: "Submitting a form" *includes* "unloading the page" (unless you use ajax to send the form's contents). You will need to include the prevention in the following page, i.e. the results page to where the form was sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit the form using AJAX rather than the form's built-in action. The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

replace the contents of formSubmitted with this:

```
sessionStorage.formSubmittedFlag=true;
notReloaded=true;
```

And replace the contents of window.onbeforeunload with this:

```
    if(sessionStorage.formSubmittedFlag===true&&notReloaded!=true)
        return 'do you want to leave?';
```